# How to run "az deployment group" command with serviceprincipal

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-devops-server-2019

As part of automating alert creation in Loganalytic workspace,We are using AzureDevops Server and looking for a way to run `az deployment group` command in Azuredevops pipeline. We have a working pipeline to execute the  ADO tasks in Subscription-A like `AzureCLI` and `AzureResourceGroupDeployment` using the predefined `serviceconnection` configured with the service principal{SP-A} which is having required access on Subscripion A and it is working as expected.

Now we got the requirement to execute same pipeline to Subscription B, where the current used servicePrincipal SP-A does not have subscription level access. So we are blocked with the further steps as we are only allowed to get the specific access (like create or modify alert rule in LAW- Microsoft.Insights/ScheduledQueryRules/[Read, Write, Delete] )  for the SP-A to create the alert rules in Loganalyticworkspace of subscription B.

So we are looking for guidance on below things.

- Is it possible to configure a service connection to Subscription B using the same SP-A that only has the Microsoft.Insights/ScheduledQueryRules/[Read, Write, Delete]  permission on the LAW, and not having any access to subscription B or resource group of LAW-B
- If the above method will not work, is there any way to run `az group deploy` commands with service Pricipal credentails by adding in to the command as paramaters.

The working ADO tasks for subs A is as follows and looking for a solution if we can use same for Sub B

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: "verify the deployment changes"
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.subscription }}
    scriptType: 'bash'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: 'az deployment group what-if --resource-group ${{ parameters.resourceGroup }} --template-file $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/template.json --parameters $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/param.json'
- task: AzureResourceGroupDeployment@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.subscription }}
    action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
    resourceGroupName: ${{ parameters.resourceGroup }}
    location: ${{ parameters.region }}
    templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
    csmFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/template.json'
    csmParametersFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/param.json'
    deploymentMode: 'Incremental'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to configure a service connection to Subscription B
> using the same SP-A that only has the
> Microsoft.Insights/ScheduledQueryRules/[Read, Write, Delete]
> permission on the LAW, and not having any access to subscription B or
> resource group of LAW-B

***It will be not possible as you will be creating [`custom role`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles) with only `Microsoft.Insights/ScheduledQueryRules/*` which is required for managing/creating Scheduled Query Alerts but for the service account to find the LAW and Deploy the Alerts using the resource group deployment will at least require `read` permission on subscription or resource group  and `Microsoft/Resources/deployments/*` to create deployments.***

**You can check these [`built-in roles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#monitor) for Azure Monitor.**

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. Could you please clear the statement read permission on subscription or resource group and Microsoft/Resources/deployments/* to create deployments." I could understand that the the SP-A needs the read acces on the Resourcegroup of LAW atleast and this part is not clear `Microsoft/Resources/deployments/* `. Also inorder to use the ADO task, which i gave above, will this allow to create the service connection or i can use only azure cli command with the service principal which is having the custom access

Comment: `Could you please clear the statement read permission on subscription or resource group and Microsoft/Resources/deployments/* to create deployments." I could understand that the the SP-A needs the read acces on the Resourcegroup of LAW atleast and this part is not clear Microsoft/Resources/deployments/* `
This means  that the `service account which is being used by the ADO task` should have `deployments access` on sub / resource group as it will be creating alerts by `az group deployment`

Comment: `Also inorder to use the ADO task, which i gave above, will this allow to create the service connection or i can use only azure cli command with the service principal which is having the custom access` If the subscription are in same tenant then you don't need to create diff service connection again you have to just create custom access on the 2nd sub and grant it to the service connection ..

Comment: we are using ADO service conenction of Azure Resource Manager using service principal (manual) only and  for each of our subscription we have seperate service connection.  The alert creation we are now trying for Sub B where the SP-A doesnt have subecription level access, So as you mentioned in your comments, if the SP-A get the custom access on RG of LAW, by the same service principal can we create the ADO service connetion to Sub B ?

Comment: yes , if the subscriptions are in same Azure AD tenant only.

Comment: But What I understood from the docs is that, We cant create a service connection in ADO to a subscription without having access to the subscription level. In our case we wont get access for the serviceprincipal to the subscription level and only possible to get the custom access on the resourcegroup of LAW  like for executing resourcegroup deployments and custom permission on the LAW to create alerts. But according to you this custom access of Service principal is enough to create the ADO service connection. Please correct me if i am wrong with my understanding from your comments

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242012/discussion-between-vowneee-and-ansumanbal-mt).